# Using Templatetags with Django Ratings

Tags: django, rating-system, templatetags

I am using dcramer's [djangoratings](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings) to try to implement a ratings system, but am having problems using some of the templatetags that he mentions.

My model is:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    rating = RatingField(range=3)
```

I am trying to use the templatetags included in the package to get the user's vote as described here:

> **rating_by_request**
>
> Retrieves the Vote cast by a user on a particular object and stores it
>   in a context variable. If the user has not voted, the context variable
>   will be 0:
>
> {% rating_by_request request on instance.field as vote %}
>
> **rating_by_user**
>
> Retrieves the Vote cast by a user on a particular object and stores it
>   in a context variable. If the user has not voted, the context variable
>   will be 0:
>
> {% rating_by_user user on instance.field as vote %}

But may be using them incorrectly,

```
{% rating_by_user user on Thing.rating as vote %}
{{ vote }}
{% rating_by_request request on Thing.rating as rate %}
{{ rate }}
```

.. Because `{{ vote }}` and `{{ rate }}` don't return any values. How do I use these tags to get the objects as described? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set in view context `thing` or `Thing` variable? If in view `'thing': Thing.objects.get(...)`

```
{% rating_by_user user on thing.rating as vote %}
{{ vote }}
{% rating_by_request request on thing.rating as rate %}
{{ rate }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using lowercase in my view, and capitalized in my template. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

{{}} this tag is used for display the information.
if you want to get information from user you should try something like
in .html file

```
<form action="address of your view" method="get">
{%csrf_token%}
<input type="text" name="vote"/ >
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

in your view

```
vote_val=request.GET.get('vote','default_value')
```

now vote is stored in vote_val

Comment: Sorry, but this does not really apply to my question.